# C# assembly - get path where it was before being registered with gacutil

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, gac, gacutil

Is there any way to get the path of an assembly registered with gacutil /i myassembly.dll ?

I mean the path where the .dll file was at the moment it was registered with this command. All that I get right now is the path in the GAC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. When you register an assembly in GAC, gacutil makes a copy of the dll in Windows\assembly (or Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly for .NET 4.0). It doesn't keep any info on the location of the original assembly.

**EDIT:**
You can however add a custom trace to your assembly when installing, using `/ir` option instead of `/i`

```
gacutil /ir myassembly.dll OPAQUE "Custom application details" "Custom description"
```

and then retrieve the details using `/lr` option

```
gacutil /lr myassembly.dll
```

More info on tracing [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c.aspx)